# PS3 skyrim eye of the magnus tolfdir starts fighting me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After defeating ancano I'm suppose to talk to tolfdir but he starts fighting me and won't let me talk to him. I've tried leaving the castle and waiting fast forwarding time but when it comes back he's outside the castle fighting me. So I go back in and let him defeat me but going outside saved it so I'm pretty much stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why he might suddenly be attacking you. They are:

- **You have unknowingly become a stage 4 vampire or a werewolf.**
- **There is a bounty on your head.**
- **Lastly, a more obscure reason is that you have stolen goods before and have never been caught.**

If your reason is the last, then it takes more than a few "disease-curing potions" to fix this. First of all, one must look for an NPC (most preferably a guard) and hit him. **BE WARNED. DO NOT KILL HIM** simply hit him, and quickly **SHEATHE YOUR WEAPON**. By doing so, the guard would most often not begin to attack you. Instead, a small bounty will be placed over your head and he will request of you to pay it off. Simply do as you are told (I know its hard) and pay the bounty. This usually "resets" the system, allowing you to stop getting attacked.

**In other words, check for those reasons above first.** If the problem continues to persist, please inform me. However, if it does, it probably is a another annoying bug the you are going to have to report.

Note: In case you ever need to know how to prevent or stop the other 2 reasons, please do not hesitate to ask.